# Test API endpoints with AWS SDK integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, mux

I'm trying to test my API endpoint that list files from an AWS S3 Bucket:

```golang
func listFiles(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    client := GetAWSClient()
    bucket := aws.String(BUCKETNAME)

    input := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: bucket,
    }

    resp, err := GetObjects(context.TODO(), client, input)
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }

    msg, _ := json.Marshal(resp.Contents)
    w.WriteHeader(200)
    w.Write(msg)
    return
}
...

func handleRequest() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/listFiles", listFiles).Methods("GET")
    c := cors.Default()
    handler := c.Handler(myRouter)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler))
}
```

I see from AWS SDK documentation that to mock AWS client functions you can use it interface so in my `main_test.go` I created these:

```golang
//Testing /listFiles endpoint

type mockListObjectsAPI func(ctx context.Context, params *s3.ListObjectsV2Input, optFns ...func(*s3.Options)) (*s3.ListObjectsV2Output, error)

func (m mockListObjectsAPI) ListObjectsV2(ctx context.Context, params *s3.ListObjectsV2Input, optFns ...func(*s3.Options)) (*s3.ListObjectsV2Output, error) {
    return m(ctx, params, optFns...)
}

func TestGetObjectFromS3(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct {
        client func(t *testing.T) S3ListObjectsAPI
        bucket string
        key    string
        expect []byte
    }{
        {
            client: func(t *testing.T) S3ListObjectsAPI {
                return mockListObjectsAPI(func(ctx context.Context, params *s3.ListObjectsV2Input, optFns ...func(*s3.Options)) (*s3.ListObjectsV2Output, error) {
                    t.Helper()
                    if params.Bucket == nil {
                        t.Fatal("expect bucket to not be nil")
                    }
                    if e, a := "fooBucket", *params.Bucket; e != a {
                        t.Errorf("expect %v, got %v", e, a)
                    }
                    return &s3.ListObjectsV2Output{
                        Name: aws.String("fooBucket"),
                    }, nil
                })
            },
            bucket: "fooBucket",
            key:    "barKey",
            expect: []byte("this is the body foo bar baz"),
        },
        //Add more test cases here if needed
    }

    for i, tt := range cases {
        t.Run(strconv.Itoa(i), func(t *testing.T) {
           //Here I should compare API returned value with expected in the test cases
        })
    }
}
```

My question is, how could I test my API calling it from the test but without calling AWS but instead using the values I mocked?

If I use httptest to call the endpoint it will call the real endpoint calling AWS.

Comment: does this work for you?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3iface/

Comment: That's for create the interface in v1, I followed this one: https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/unit-testing/ .However that's not the problem now. I need to know how to test the API without calling AWS.

Comment: 3 techniques I have used for this: organizing code so that I can test most behavior with crafted  stub responses; using localstack for testing (not always an awesome experience in Go, as python sdk is sloppy on the spec), or using sandbox account for testing and having testing scaffolding set up as part of the testing process.  Looking forward to reading others' answers